# Symfony linking to an admin Table record edit page

Tags: symfony1, routes, symfony-1.4

kind of finding it difficult to wrap my head around this. For those who have used the Symfony admin generator extensively, for each module based of a backend module, there is an edit page for all the records. Typically this can be accessed like this:

```
module/primarykey/edit.  (assume questions/1/edit)
```

which is strange because typically the primary key would be passed in as a URI parameter like:

questions/edit/1. Anyways, that maybe irrelevant. What is important is how do I manage to generate a link_to for the above URI. I am linking the editSuccess page through an external page which does not belong to the UI. The syntax I use is

```
link_to('Edit','questions/'.$primary_key.'/edit') // (where $primary_key = 1 as in this case)
```

However that auto modifies itself to :

/backend_dev.php/questions/1/action **note the action instead of edit**

No such action exists and it returns a 404 error stating that questions/action does not exist

To summarize, How do you link to an admin page that renders specifically for a record?

Answer (score 1):

The `url_for` (and thus the `link_to`) helpers deal with *internal* urls, not external ones. The syntax is `module/action?parameters`. In your case this would be `question/edit?id=$primarykey` (assuming the action looks for the id parameter).

If you give a name to your route, that makes generating the link faster (hashtable lookup vs. linear search):

```
echo url_for("@question_edit?id=$primary_key");
```

If you set up your route as an sfDoctrineRoute, it gets even simpler:

```
echo url_for("question_edit", $question);
```

note how you need not pass the id, but the question object - the route class will fetch all neccessary parameters.